# Recovering data from RAID 0 after reinstalling Windows

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bios, raid, data-recovery

I have the following setup on my system:

- 4 SDDs in RAID0 with Windows 10.
- 1 standalone SSD

The RAID was created on BIOS using Intel's Rapid Storage Utility.

In my attempt to setup Ubuntu on the standalone SSD, after installation, I mistakenly issued the command `dmraid -rE`, and typed `yes` to all prompts. Then, I lost my RAID and couldn't boot into Windows. I rebuilt the RAID and reinstalled Windows 10 with the same SSDs, same drive order and same stripe size (128KB), again on BIOS.

I had some files in the Desktop folder of the previous installation and I am wondering if I can at least have a list of the file names that were there, since they were most probably lost forever.

Software I have already tried unsuccessfully:

- EaseUS Data Recovery.
- Stellar Phoenix RAID Recovery
- ReclaiMe Free RAID Recovery

Stellar cannot see the SSDs separately in order to reconstruct the RAID so I just chose the current RAID and did a deep scan by setting the stripe size to 128KB and the starting sector to 0. ReclaiMe does not allow selecting only one drive for RAID so I couldn't run it. EaseUS could run but found only files of the current installation.

Is there anything else I can do? Is there any file that could have stored the filenames that were in Desktop?

Comment: "Is there anything else I can do?" - Send all 4 disks, RAID controller, to a data recovery specialist.  However, if you overwrote the data, you are out of luck.  The time to attempt data recovery was before you reinstalled Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound You forgot to add that the user would probably need to include a credit card with a fair amount of credit on it... Because this type of data recovery is incredibly expensive. We had to do data recovery on a 500GB hard drive once, recovered 200GB of data and it was over a $1000. RAID's are generally exponentially more expensive to recover usable data.

Comment: @Ramhound Of course, reinstalling Windows was the end of story. So, just to have it in mind for the future. But, before attempting recovery, would you recreate the RAID array or leave the array dismantled?

Comment: @acejavelin The worth of the data is not so much. It's just my peace of mind since I cannot remember what was there. But I appreciate your sense of humor.

Comment: @acejavelin Ok?  Proper backups are cheap.

Comment: The moral of the story is do not use a RAID 0 configuration on systems you **do not backup but expect redundancy and/or backups**. You need to be sure you understand how to recover from the backups after rebuilding the RAID as well. With RAID 0 you get no disk redundancy and if any one of the drives in the array of a RAID 0 die, there is no parity so the entire array dies. It's not even RAID in the sense of "redundancy". Long story short, switch to RAID 5 perhaps if you need redundancy and start backing up and restoring both so you know how, what, etc. when it's time to do what needs done.

Comment: If you want disk performance with no redundancy then perhaps RAID 0 is what you want but if you are expecting to be able to recover when the system hoses up or RAID breaks, then make sure you understand all aspects of the configuration including the RAID configuration, how different types affect disk space, redundancy, etc. I say go with a RAID 5 with the 4 or maybe even all 5 as a RAID 5 and just lose one for parity and buy an additional for a hot spare onsite. How critical is your data, how critical is this system, understand your needs and system and processes thoroughly and with detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Stellar’s Raid Recovery can automatically create a virtual RAID if a user does not know the RAID Parameters. You should be able to see the different drives on the top right panel and if it’s not showing up that means your drives are not connected in the correct order in SATA, once you get that right select ‘Don’t Know start sector of drive’ and tick all the probable sectors, then select ‘Don’t Know’ in Select Stripe Size this will build your RAID and then you’ll be able to recover all the RAID data.
Once the data is recovered, Its advised to avoid RAID 0 and switch to RAID 5, RAID 6 or RAID 10 for better data redundancy.

Comment: If you read my whole post and the discussion, you should see that this is a special case where most of the data is overwritten by the time I rebuilt the array and reinstalled Windows. My hope was that I could restore the directory list i.e. a list of the files and folders I had in Desktop but it is also too hard. If you know something about this, let me know. Thanks.